# Using Scanner and Pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read doubles from file:

```
14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065,1
13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050,1
(...)
```

Using this method:

```
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
(...)
value = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next(Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)")));
(...)
values.add(value);
```

But this doesn't work! I have InputMismatchException, but without message so I completely don't know what is going on. Is pattern wrong or something?

Comment: Any reason you're not using [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--)?

Comment: I tried but I had InputMismatchException too.

Comment: use better `Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine.split(",")).stream().map(Double::parseDouble).forEach(System.out::println/* or do something else here */);`

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter used by Scanner by default is whitespace, but in your data file, obviously you use comma, i.e., "," as delimiter. And that is the reason.

If you want to find the next match and ignore delimiter, use `scanner.findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)"), 0);`
and if you data stays in one line, use `findInLine(pattern)`.

Or you can also assign delimiter, using `scanner.useDelimiter(String pattern)`, in your case maybe `scanner.useDelimiter(",")`
Please Read

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html